# Open file selected in CDockablePane in MFC MDI application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I want to open some file, that double clicked in `CDockablePane` (`CFileView` in Visual Studio template MDI project). Here I got a file name:

```
BOOL CFileView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
    HTREEITEM hRes=m_wndFileView.GetSelectedItem();
    CString s = m_wndFileView.GetItemText(hRes);
}
}
```

Now I want `OnFileNew` or `OnFileOpen` with parameters (my file name), but only I can do from `CFileView` do is message sending:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_NEW, 0);
```

How can I send this message with parameters to my `CDocument` class, or use `CDocument::OnNewDocument` with parameters directly from my `CFileView` class?

Comment: `CView` has a [`GetDocument()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#getdocument) member that allows you to refer to the document from a view.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, but I did not understand how to create new document with params from CDockablePane using CView.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I created a new test-project with VS: MDI Application, "Visual Studio" Project style, which creates many `CDockablePane` windows. `CFileView` (`CDockablePane`-derived) contains a member variable `m_wndFileView`, of type `CViewTree`, which is `CTreeCtrl`-derived.

Your first goal is to catch the double-click event. Tree-View controls don't have some `OnItemDoubleClick()` handler, but they send the `NM_DBLCLK` notification. The notification is processed by the control's parent, which is the `CFileView` window. Therefore you have to override the `OnNotify()` member of your `CFileView` class (from Class View, Overrides tab) and process the notification there. You can open an existing document or create a new one. So your code can be:

```
BOOL CFileView::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMHDR* pNMHDR = (NMHDR*)lParam;
    if (pNMHDR && pNMHDR->code == NM_DBLCLK && pNMHDR->hwndFrom == m_wndFileView.m_hWnd)
    {
        HTREEITEM hItem = m_wndFileView.GetSelectedItem();
        if (hItem)
        {
            CString s = m_wndFileView.GetItemText(hItem);
            CDocument *pDoc = theApp.OpenDocumentFile(GetFullCXUpm13DocPathName(s)); // Opens an existing document-file
            if (pDoc)
                static_cast<CXUpm13Doc*>(pDoc)->initialEntity = _T("https://example.site/main/product_all?Cat=") + findCat(s);
        }
    }

    return CDockablePane::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
}
```

To create a new document instead of opening an existing one you can call:

```
    theApp.m_pDocManager->OnFileNew();
```

or,

```
    pCXUpm13DocTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(NULL);
```

For more details about document-template and document creation and management functions check the `CWinApp`, `CDocTemplate` and `CDocManager` class documentation, and maybe their headers and sources I would say.

Comment: Can I send some parameters to theApp.m_pDocManager->OnFileNew(); ?

Comment: @СергейСоколов, By setting paremeters in the document, I guess you mean that `initialEntity` member. Well, this requires a pointer to the document. Unfortunately the `OnFileNew()` members of both `CWinApp` and `CDocManager` return `void`. However `CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(NULL)` returns a pointer to the newly created document. As noted in the comment, you have to store the `pDocTemplate` ptr created in `InitInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution; any suggestions for improvement are welcome:

```
BOOL CFileView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) 
    {
    HTREEITEM hRes=m_wndFileView.GetSelectedItem();
    CString s = m_wndFileView.GetItemText(hRes);
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
    pMainFrame->m_wndOutput.AddStringStatusTab(_T("File Open Process"));
    POSITION pos = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
    if (pos != nullptr) 
    {
        CDocTemplate* pTemplate = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate(pos);
        CXUpm13Doc* pDoc = static_cast<CXUpm13Doc*>(pTemplate->CreateNewDocument());
        pDoc->initialEntity = _T("https://example.site/main/product_all?Cat="+ findCat(s));
        pDoc->OnNewDocument();
        if (pDoc != nullptr) {
            CFrameWnd* pFrame = pTemplate->CreateNewFrame(pDoc, nullptr);
            if (pFrame != nullptr) {
                pTemplate->SetDefaultTitle(pDoc);
                pTemplate->InitialUpdateFrame(pFrame, pDoc, TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return CDockablePane::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Try `CDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile()`, instead of creating, associating, initializing etc etc all items yourself. The doc-template pointer can be stored (as a global or otherwise single-instance variable), once created in your `CMyApp::InitInstance()` override, instead of enumerating doc-templates, only to pick the first one. `CWinApp` also has an `OpenDocumentFile()` method, you can try this too, it may be simpler actually.

Comment: Also, can't you catch the double-click event in your `CFileView` class? Doesn't it offer some sort `OnItemDoubleClick()` event? That is, do you really need to use `PretranslateMessage()`?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou OnItemDoubleClick() in CFileView does not work. Other advices I will try, thank you.